# Why do I have to call query twice?

Tags: php, sql

why do I need to query twice here? Why can't I just query the one below, change it to 'SELECT * FROM ...' and use it query for the rest of the script? When I try to do that, the second half part of my script won't recognize the query from the beginning, and I have to query again.
`$getImages = 'SELECT image_id, image_name FROM images';`

```
<select name="image_id">
    <?php while ($row = $images->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
        <option value="<?= $row['image_id']; ?>"
            <?php if (isset($_GET['image_id']) && $_GET['image_id'] == $row['image_id']) {
                echo 'selected';
            } ?>
            ><?= $row['image_name']; ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
```

```
$sql = "SELECT image_name, caption FROM images WHERE image_id = $image_id";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows) {
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
?>
<figure><img src="images/<?= $row['image_name']; ?>.jpg" width=600px height=auto>
    <figcaption><?= $row['caption']; ?></figcaption>
</figure>
<?php } else { ?>
    <p>Image not found</p>
<?php } ?>
```

thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first loop exhausts all the results of the query. You need to either re-execute the query or rewind the result resource back to the first record.

Answer (score 0):

Far far far easier to pull your object to an array, then iterate through the array so that you aren't getting stuck with exhausting our object rows.

Comment: $results = mysqli_fetch_all($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC); then loop through results.